# Send SMS through Asp.net via gsm modem

Tags: c#, asp.net, communication, gsm

Is it possible to detect GSM mobile (any kind) which connected
through serial port to computer and then be able to send SMS through
this mobile phone to other mobile phones from asp.net website running under iis(only 1 system), could anyone help me and guide
me, I wrote a program which could open COM port but still couldn't
detect mobile phone and send SMS through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modem or phone will need to be connected serial port of the same server machine on which ur asp.net app is running. codeplex has some gud libs tht can do this for you. but I strongly recommend not to do it this way. rather prefer a 3rd party http gateway which can give u much higher throughput with reliability.